# hiding permalink in admin if the user is subscriber

Tags: posts, permalinks

I don't want to show the permalink if the user is subscriber. Can anyone help me to achieve that?

PS: I'm talking about the permalink which appears `below title` while creating new post.

PPS: I modified the rules for subscriber. They can able to submit the post for review

Comment: Subscribers cannot create new posts. Are you talking about the contributor role?

Comment: No i modified the rules for subscriber. They can able to submit the post for review

Comment: Please notate that in your question as it innately will cause some confusion with the out-of-the-box role permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hide_slug_box() {
    global $post;
    global $pagenow;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='post-new.php' OR $pagenow=='post.php') {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                jQuery('#edit-slug-box').hide();
            });
            </script>
        ";
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_slug_box'  );
```

Comment: Just wondering why you accepted the previous answer, then posted your own answer. Which answer is correct?

Comment: Actually i thought Yoav Aner answer is right. So i accepted it. But when i try it, it actually removes slug metabox which is wrong. So i posted the new answer. My answer is right and its working. But i need to wait 2 days to accept my answer

Comment: @Virthagirl ahh I see. :)

Answer (score 4):

maybe this can do the trick? (untested). Note I used contributor role (Thanks to Brian Fegter for pointing this out)

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    if (current_user_can('contributor')) {
        remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'post', 'normal');
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Hi i think hook will be `do_meta_boxes` instead of `admin_menu`

Comment: ok, just used another example from somewhere without testing it. If you say that's working then I'd update the answer for future reference.

Comment: No i guess you are right. So don't change anything

Comment: Hi the code you given is to hide slug metabox. Not that permalink edit box. Let me post the answer

Answer (score 1):

i think it is better to use css than to use jQuery to hide the element...

instead of the script part i use

```
 echo "<style>
       #edit-slug-box {display:none!important}
        </style>
    ";
```